# Why can't I switch user?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

I have an ubuntu desktop vm on VMware workstation.

I can connect to it with one of my user. Here `LoukMouk`.

When I try to use the option switch user situated at the top right corner of the GUI, it doesn't send me to the page to choose what user I want to connect as... Its like it only locks my session waiting for me to enter my password.

[image]

I don't know why... This doesn't always happen, sometimes, when I try a second/third time, it finaly shows me the selection...

Is it possible that my limited amount of ram could prevent me from opening a second session? I mean... It works sometimes... I'm confused.

Am I the only one having this issue? (:

Comment: Did you installed this image of Ubuntu recently?
You may try entering Alt + F2 and type "r" without quotes to refresh the gnome environment and see if the options come back.

Comment: @R4wd0G Thanks for the tip, I'll try it when I won't be able to switch users again. Just out of curiosity, does this command restart the gnome environment without restarting the whole machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been asked: [Switch user not working in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011763/switch-user-not-working-in-17-10)

As the answer to that question says, this is a bug in GNOME. Meanwhile, you can hit `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` (with `fn` if needed) to go to the login screen and switch the user.